# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null en laravel

Tags: javascript, html

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null es el error que me da con este código.

Estoy con un proyecto de laravel en el que tengo que meter un div con unos tabs para separar en dos pestañas información.

la pagina esta con bootstrap y jquery por si sirve de algo, no se porque me salta este error y las tabs no funcionan.

El código lo he cogido de codepen y allí funciona, ya he probado todas las posibles soluciones que hay en artículos anteriores aquí y ninguno funciona.

también he revisado el css y ninguna clase parece estar entorpeciendo a el css de este bloque.

no se que mas puedo probar.

**//Javascript:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var tab1 = document.getElementById('tab-1');//en estas 4 lineas da error
    var tab2 = document.getElementById('tab-2');
    var item1 = document.getElementById('item-1');
    var item2 = document.getElementById('item-2');
    tab1.addEventListener('click', function(){
        this.classList.add('activeTab'),
        tab2.classList.remove('activeTab'),
        item1.classList.add('activeItem'),
        item2.classList.remove('activeItem');
    });
    tab2.addEventListener('click', function(){
        this.classList.add('activeTab'),
        tab1.classList.remove('activeTab'),
        item2.classList.add('activeItem'),
        item1.classList.remove('activeItem');
    });
</script>
```

**//CSS:**

```
<style type="text/css">
    .container-tabs{
        position: relative;
        z-index: 100;
        width: 100%;
        height: 40px;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: flex-start;
    }
    .tab{
        padding: 0 30px;
        color: #fff;
        font-family: 'open sans', sans-serif;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        border-top-left-radius: 10px;
        border-top-right-radius: 10px;
        border: 2px solid #fff;
        background: #000;
        cursor: pointer;
        margin-right: 2px;
    }
    .container-description{
        width: 100%;
        height: 350px;
        position: relative;
        z-index: 90;
    }
    .item{
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        font-family: 'Georgia', serif;
        line-height: 23px;
        background-color: #f0f0f0;
        padding: 30px 50px 0 50px;
        border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
        letter-spacing: 1px;
        display: none;
    }
    .item-1{
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 100;
    }
    .activeTab{
        background-color: #fff;
        color: black;
    }
    .activeItem{
        display: block;
    }
</style>
```

**//HTML:**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="container-tabs">
        <div class="tab activeTab" id="tab-1">Opcion 1</div>
        <div class="tab" id="tab-2">Opcion 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="container-description">
        <div class="description-item1 item activeItem" id="item-1">
            1 
        </div>
        <div class="description-item2 item" id="item-2">
            2 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Invocar un elemento HTML por medio de JavaScript antes de que este exista en el DOM generará que este te retorne un valor **`NULL`**.

Entonces debes mover la lógica de JS al final de tu documento HTML justo antes de la etiqueta de cierre de **`body`**

Revisemos este ejemplo:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <title>JS Bin</title>
      <script>
        let titulo = document.querySelector("h1")
        console.log(titulo.innerText)
      </script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <h1>Hola Mundo</h1>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Nos devuelve:

- Si invocamos solo a la variable un resultado de NULL
- Si tratamos de acceder a la propiedad **`innerText`** nos dará este mensaje de error:

> "error" "TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerText' of null

Mientras que si lo movemos a la sección donde te indico:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <title>JS Bin</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <h1>Hola Mundo</h1>
      <script>
        let titulo1 = document.querySelector("h1")
        console.log(titulo1.innerText)
      </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Obtenemos como salida:

> Hola Mundo